# How can I get to know that end of page has reached while creating a PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How can I come to know that the next line of my PDF will start from the next page? Is there anyway in the itext that it can handle this thing automatically. Currently I have a pdf which is being created perfectly, but when the value of a field is more than the page, then the page is being neglected and the execution starts from the next page but I have to utilize that current page as well.

The **structure** that I am using is as follows

I have used a PdfPCell', in which I have added 'Paragraph's... and "Paragraph"s are constructed by "Elements".

**Problem:**
Problem here is that the final paragraph is constructed with all of the elements(text) which is more than one page and itext neglects first page and starts execution from the next.

Suggestions Required:

Is there a way, that itext should know that the doc is multipage and it starts utilizing the first page?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you use setSplitRows or setSplitLate?

Comment: no, where to use them and where is the documentation SINA?

Comment: In PdfPTable. But default values are fine, then this  is not your problem.

Comment: Are you really required to put the paragraphs into a table cell? Table cells which are larger than the page somehow seem wrong.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it? if it is then please let me know.